# Customize Next/Previous links in Minimum Pro Genesis theme

Tags: php, wordpress

Here's the page in question: http://www.affordableonlinedegrees.net/blog/

I can style the links just fine—that's not my issue. It’s the text and double-angle quotes I’d like to be able to change to something custom.

In genesis/lib/structure/post.php there’s the below function. How do I edit this properly as a child theme file?
And more specifically, how would I change the ascii double angle quotes ( « and » ) to something of my choice? i.e. a custom background image like an arrow?

```
function genesis_prev_next_posts_nav() {

    $prev_link = get_previous_posts_link( apply_filters( 'genesis_prev_link_text', '&#x000AB;' . __( 'Previous Page', 'genesis' ) ) );
    $next_link = get_next_posts_link( apply_filters( 'genesis_next_link_text', __( 'Next Page', 'genesis' ) . '&#x000BB;' ) );

    $prev = $prev_link ? '<div class="pagination-previous alignleft">' . $prev_link . '</div>' : '';
    $next = $next_link ? '<div class="pagination-next alignright">' . $next_link . '</div>' : '';

    $nav = genesis_markup( array(
        'html5'   => '<div %s>',
        'xhtml'   => '<div class="navigation">',
        'context' => 'archive-pagination',
        'echo'    => false,
    ) );

    $nav .= $prev;
    $nav .= $next;
    $nav .= '</div>';

    if ( $prev || $next )
        echo $nav;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assumed you are using version 2.0 and up. Add codes below to your child theme functions.php. I included icons to change wp default pre/nextlabel, change whatever you want.

```
add_action('genesis_entry_footer', 'custom_pagination_links', 15 );
function custom_pagination_links() {
if( !is_single() ) 
      return;

    previous_post_link('<span class="single-post-nav previous-post-link">%link</span>', '<i class=\'fa fa-arrow-circle-o-left\'></i> ' . get_previous_post_link('%title') , FALSE);
    next_post_link('<span class="single-post-nav next-post-link">%link</span>', get_next_post_link('%title') . ' <i class=\'fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right\'></i>' , FALSE);
}
```

The rest job is styling, it's up to you.

best regards,
dnb